# Why is format method from NumberFormat class calling subclass format method?

Tags: java

I have a Main.java and in the main method I have the following code:

```
totalSalaries = 14000;
System.out.printf("The total payout should be %s%n", currencyInstance.format(totalSalaries));
```

I tried to run the above statement in debug mode to understand the traversal of how the format method gets called.

When you step-in the above format method, it inturn calls the below format method which belongs to NumberFormat class (where NumberFormat extends Format)

```
public final String format(long number) {
    return format(number, new StringBuffer(),
                  DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
}
```

Upon then, clicking on the format method above (of NumberFormat class) within this return block, it seems to land on the below which is part of the DecimalFormat class (where DecimalFormat extends NumberFormat).

```
@Override
public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer result,
                           FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
    fieldPosition.setBeginIndex(0);
    fieldPosition.setEndIndex(0);

    return format(number, result, fieldPosition.getFieldDelegate());
}
```

Could someone kindly explain why the NumberFormat class is calling format method of it's subclass DecimalFormat? It shouldn't be possible isn't it ? Thanks for your help

Comment: What type is `currencyInstance`?

Comment: Here it is:
NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

Comment: What IDE are you using? I cannot reproduce "clicking on the format method above within this return block, it seems to land on the below which is part of the DecimalFormat class"

Comment: @Sweeper: Using IntelliJ (with Java19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to observe is that [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is an abstract class:

> `public abstract class` **`NumberFormat`**

That means that when you call `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` what you will get is an instance of a concrete subclass of `NumberFormat` - in most cases that will probably be a `DecimalFormat` instance.

The `format(long number)` method in `NumberFormat` is

```
public final String format(long number) {
    return format(number, new StringBuffer(),
                  DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
}
```

And it calls the method `format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)` which in `NumberFormat` is declared as abstract method:

```
public abstract StringBuffer format(long number,
                                    StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                                    FieldPosition pos);
```

For a class to be instanciable it must not have any abstract methods - if it extends an abstract base class, it must implement all the abstract methods of its parent class. And if you look at the [implementation of `DecimalFormat`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#L708) it implements that method:

> ```
> public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer result,
>                            FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
>     fieldPosition.setBeginIndex(0);
>     fieldPosition.setEndIndex(0);
>
>     return format(number, result, fieldPosition.getFieldDelegate());
> }
> ```

What you see in the debugger (that it steps through the `format` method in `NumberFormat` and then calls the `format` method in `DecimalFormat`) is due to the fact the method `format(long number)` is declared in the `NumberFormat` class. The currencyInstance is however always a `DecimalFormat` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain this sentence: "That means that when you call NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); what you will get is an instance of a concrete subclass of NumberFormat - in most cases that will probably be a DecimalFormat instance."- this I wasn't aware of nor have I seen this explained in any courses or videos.

Also I just happened to quickly crosscheck by doing a System.out.println(currencyInstance.getClass().getName()) and it returned an object of DecimalFormat which then seems to make perfect sense. But I just can't seem to wrap my head around that logic.

Comment: Sorry ... but I am not sure what *needs* to be explained about that sentence.  What part don't you understand?

Comment: @StephenC: sorry my previous comment was only partial. I have edited it above.

Comment: The logic is that `NumberFormat` is an `abstract` class.  Therefore a bare `NumberFormat` instance **cannot** exist.  (That's what `abstract` means.)  Therefore what you get from the call `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` **cannot** be a base `NumberFormat` instance.  It **must** be an instance of a *subclass* of `NumberFormat` instead.  And subclasses are allowed to override methods that they inherit.

Comment: But as a general rule, a method that is declared as returning an instance of class `C` is permitted by the Java type system to return instances of any subclass of `C` as well.  (Constructors are different ... but that's not what is being used here.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen and Thomas. We may close this thread ( I dont have the rights to this myself)

Comment: @Sam on stackoverflow we cannot close threads. If my post is (in your opinion) a good answer to your question you should accept it (click the checkmark) - as a benefit you will gain some reputation too.